# css to design a dashbard template

Tags: html, css

I am tryingg to design and simple css template for my dashboard. Like to have top section to display the logo and the title, left section for the menu, center to display info based on the menu, right to display some info, bottom to display some contact info. I like left/center/right side of the page to be vertically and horizontally scorllable. When scrolled, I need the header to be always showing on the browser.

can anybody help me with this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Dashboard Layout</title>
<STYLE type="text/css">
#top {
height: 100px;
widht: auto;
border-bottom: 5px solid;
}

#left {
height: auto;
width: 350px;
border: 1px solid;
float: left;
overflow: scroll;

}

#content {
width: auto;
height: auto;
float: left;
overflow: scroll;
}

#right {
height: auto;
width: 350px;
float: right;
overflow: auto;
}

#bottom {

height: 50px;
width: auto;
}



</STYLE>

</head>
<body>

<div id="top">

        <h3><b>Dashboard</b></h3>

</div>

<div id="middle">

<div id="left">

        <h3><b>Menu</b></h3>
</div>

<div id="content">


         <div id="div1" </div>

</div>


<div id="right">
        <h3><b>Definitions</b></h3>

</div>

</div>

<div id="bottom">

        <p>This dasboard prodides info about systems.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to provide some evidence that you have actually attempted to try and create this yourself or you will not receive any help on this site.  If you are looking for someone to write all your code for you, please consider hiring someone.

Comment: I'll post my code momentarily, thank you @Jrod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a div that is always visible whether or not your scroll, use:

```
.visibleDiv
{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: For the rest, can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Karan said, you have to fix the position of your header (#top). A fixed element is positioned relative to the browser window.

```
#top {
position: fixed;
width: 100%
top: 0;
height: 100px;
border-bottom: 5px solid;
}
```

Then you would see your content div (#middle) starting to overlap with the header, so you should set aside a top margin.

```
#middle {
margin-top: 100px /* the same height as your header */
}
```

And because you are floating several divs, I suggest that you [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) after them to adjust the height of the parent div.

There are many great tutorials for css menus and headers on the web, so Google them! :]